# 日付部分がローカライズできない翻訳文字列があります

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, 翻訳

https://ja.traducir.win/strings/5977 が、

> `終了日: $when$`

となっており、`$when$` はすでにフォーマットされた文字列のようなので、ローカライズできません。これを、例えば、 https://ja.traducir.win/strings/5605 のように、

> `$short_month_name$ $day_number$`

などとして下さい。

`$when$` が条件により変化する文字列である場合は、出力時に `$when$` に設定される文字列を、全て翻訳文字列として登録することで対応できると思います。既にそうなっている場合は、対象の翻訳文字列を教えて下さい。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

これは、月と日で日付をフォーマットするときにカルチャの設定を考慮に入れるために、標準化された[MonthDayPattern](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthdaypattern)を使用することで修正されました。

[これは、日本語のさまざまなDateTimeLocalizationフォーマットオプションを比較する.NETFiddleです。](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zyWdeX)

報告ありがとうございます。言語翻訳の問題はご容赦ください。間違いは修正してください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]